# Add days to pieced together date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dateadd

I have a database where, for some reason, the dates are put in like 1yymmdd.  I have been asked to create a field in a query that adds 30 days to this date.  I have transformed the date into a readable format by the following:

```
SUBSTRING(Datefield, 4, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Datefield, 6, 2) 
    + '/' + SUBSTRING(Datefield, 2, 2) AS LookLikeDate
```

I placed this in a view, and attempted to then:

```
DATEADD(dd,30, CONVERT(datetime, v.[LookLikeDate], 103)
```

I keep getting an error that says

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I then attempted to define in my View statement so that this field would be datetime from the start:

```
CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(Datefield, 4, 2) + '/' 
    + SUBSTRING(Datefield, 6, 2) + '/' 
    + SUBSTRING(Datefield, 2, 2), 103) AS LookLikeDate
```

When I got an error in that definition, to where I couldn't use the view at all, I changed the datetime to Char(8), which gave me the same varchar error I got previously.

Am I going about this wrong, and is there a way to add these days to this rediculous date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add 30 days you can do

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 30, RIGHT(datefield, 6)) NewDate
  FROM table1
```

To add 30 days and convert back to that format use

```
SELECT '1'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(dd, 30, RIGHT(datefield, 6)), 12) NewDate
  FROM table1
```

If you were to have following sample data

```
| DATEFIELD |
|-----------|
|   1130801 |
|   1130812 |
|   1120827 |
```

Then the output of two above mentioned queries would be

```
|                          NEWDATE |
|----------------------------------|
|    August, 31 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
| September, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
| September, 26 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
```

and

```
| NEWDATE |
|---------|
| 1130831 |
| 1130911 |
| 1120926 |
```

respectively.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaa25/14)** demo

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to jump back in until now and try.  I just tried, and received `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` error.  Do I need to change the format that the data is stored in?  Currently it is, stored as a Char(7).

Comment: How strange...
When I run my query as `DATEADD(dd, 30, RIGHT(datefield, 6))`, it errors.  However, when I create my View with `RIGHT(datefield, 6) NewDate` and then run a query of `DATEADD(dd, 30, v.NewDate)` on the view, it is working.

Comment: The error message suggests that you have value(s) that is(are) invalid dates. You have find these values and fix them.

Comment: Thank you!  I just went in, and found that the data I was given has some date fields set to 0.  I'm going to go talk with the requesting department today to see what is up.

Comment: How do I fix a date of 0 without changing the data?  I tried `CAST(CASE WHEN datefield = 0 THEN '001111' ELSE RIGHT(datefield,6) END AS datetime) AS NewDate` Where 001111 will not play a role in our data for a long time.  Still, when I try the `DATEADD(dd, 30, v.NewDate)` It is not adding correctly.  I looked through the data, and 0 seems to be the only anomaly.  I did find some dates of 99mmdd, where there was no 1 leading it.  Those should be picked up still in the `RIGHT(DateField, 6)`, right? Is there a way to ignore the dates of 0 that are screwing this up, or is there another problem?

Comment: I was told that the rows of data with 0 in datefield and be ignored completely, which is why I'm trying to assign them a number that doesn't appear in the dataset.  The DATEADD performed also had a `WHERE `clause of `v.NewDate <> '001111'`

Comment: If zero dates can be completely ignored just add a condition to `WHERE` clause to filter them out `WHERE datefield = '0'`. BTW you can't use an alias `NewDate` in `WHERE` clause directly because of the order of query processing. It should throw an error.

Comment: Apparently, I lied.  When I said that, I forgot that I actually need most of the datefield = '0' data in order to add some other fields together, which I put in my View.  Once querying the view, the datefield = '0' rows are no longer applicable.  That was where I meant, but didn't say, that the rows can be completely ignored.  Sorry about that.